# Generating a random out of 2 dice roll

Tags: c++

I fixed the typos that I had in my code, and now it runs perfect

```
int rollDice(int diceRoll[], int numberRolling) // Random dice rolls
{
    int values = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberRolling; i++)
    {
        diceRoll[i] = 1 + rand() % 6;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numberRolling; i++)
    {
        values = values + diceRoll[i];
    }
    return values;
}
```

Comment: Posting the entire error message would help. Remove parts of the code and see whether the error still occurs! In the end, you will get and _minimal, complete and verifiable example_: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'd rename the variable "values" to "sum".

Comment: I posted the entire code so it will be easier to test it, i hope this will help you guys

Comment: Your question is no longer a question.

Comment: You don't really need a second loop, you can sum the values in the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your first for

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberRolling, i++)
```

Should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberRolling; i++)
```

Comment: omg i feel so dumb right now, thanks